# XML drawable scale when drawing on canvas

Tags: android, canvas, drawable, android-drawable, xml-drawable

I'm trying to make a drawable that looks like circle with shadow. It needs to scale to different sizes and needs to be drawn on a canvas. I use setBounds to set coords and scale.

My drawable:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:bottom="0dp"
        android:left="5dp"
        android:right="5dp"
        android:top="10dp">
        <shape android:shape="oval">
            <size
                android:width="115dp"
                android:height="115dp" />
            <solid android:color="@color/level_button_dark" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item
        android:bottom="5dp"
        android:left="5dp"
        android:right="5dp"
        android:top="5dp">
        <shape android:shape="oval">
            <size
                android:width="115dp"
                android:height="115dp" />
            <solid android:color="@color/level_button" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

My drawing code

```
mButtonDrawable.setBounds(20, 20, 220, 220);
mButtonDrawable.draw(canvas);
mButtonDrawable.setBounds(270, 20, 370, 120);
mButtonDrawable.draw(canvas);
mButtonDrawable.setBounds(420, 20, 470, 70);
mButtonDrawable.draw(canvas);
```

Result:

[image]

I want to achieve a consistent look for all scales.
Tested on emulator api 18.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While @RexSplode approach is valid I found a way to do it with one drawable. You just shouldn't call `setBounds()` and operate with canvas.

See example below.

```
mButtonDrawable.setBounds(0, 0, mButtonDrawable.getIntrinsicWidth(), mButtonDrawable.getIntrinsicHeight());

canvas.save();
canvas.translate(20, 20);
canvas.scale(1, 1);
mButtonDrawable.draw(canvas);
canvas.restore();

canvas.save();
canvas.translate(420, 20);
canvas.scale(0.5f, 0.5f);
mButtonDrawable.draw(canvas);
canvas.restore();

canvas.save();
canvas.translate(620, 20);
canvas.scale(0.25f, 0.25f);
mButtonDrawable.draw(canvas);
canvas.restore();
```

Result:

[image]

I got an idea from [ImageView source](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/5.1.1_r1/android/widget/ImageView.java#ImageView.onDraw%28android.graphics.Canvas%29).

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your circles are bound to same coordinates. So when you call

```
public void setBounds (int left, int top, int right, int bottom)
```

it changes the coordinates, where two circles are to be drawn, **but** the distance between them should also become smaller. So I guess that one drawable will not do. You need two separate drawables for each circle. And change their bounds independently. This is how you can acchieve the desired effect.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I just found an even better solution. Please check my answer.